# META-INF directory and jdoconfig.xml missing in the project created by eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I am learning to use GWT with App Engine in Eclipse. I included the App-Engine SDK in the build path. I was reading the tutorial given here. https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine 
It says to create a file jdoconfig.xml in META-INF directory, but I cannot find a META-INF directory in my project structure.

Comment: What version of the Eclipse? What version of the Google plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tutorial `create a file StockWatcher/src/META-INF/jdoconfig.xml`.
You should create the META-INF directory under `src`

Comment: I had already ticked, 
Use Datanucleus JDO/JPA to access the datastore, while creating the project why doesn't eclipse create the META-INF/jdoconfig.xml for me then? Is it to be done manually always?

Comment: JDO and JPA are different APIs and need different configuration files (jdoconfig.xml for JDO, peristence.xml for JPA). Eclipse doesn't know which one you want and thus doesn't know which file to create.